# Generating diamond shape

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program which gets an integer and generates a diamond. The input is the diamond's side length, for example is the integer is 5 the results should be :

```
----*----
---***---
--*-*-*--
-*--*--*-
*********
-*--*--*-
--*-*-*--
---***---
----*----
```

My code right now :

```
side = int(raw_input())
x = (side * 2) - 1
middle = x // 2
a = ""
for i in range(side - 1):
    t = ["-"] * x
    t[middle - i] = "*"
    t[middle + i] = "*"
    t[middle] = "*"
    a += "".join(t)
    a += "\n"
t=a[:-1]
a += "*" * x + "\n"
a += t[::-1]
print(a)
```

what is the fastest way(not the easiest one) to generate this diamond using python 2.7?

Comment: Is this some homework? Can you show us your code and ask specific questions?

Comment: ill be adding the code right away.it was a challange in a programming competition site

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti i added the code

Comment: Who cares what's the *fastest* way is. This is a completely unrealistic and pointless task.

Comment: well you're right.but i was thinking about this for a while if there are any faster or shorter ways to do the same thing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is irrelevant and unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def Diamond(size):
    for n in (lambda x : x[:-1]+x[::-1])([size-i-1 for i in range(size)]):
        row = ["-" if i != n else "*" for i in range(size)]
        print(["".join(row[:-1] +["*"]+ row[size-2::-1]) if n != 0 else "*"*(size*2-1)][0])
```

[calling function in IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0S6I.png)